# Microsoft Chart control in WinForms app - how to display a composite chart

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, charts

I need to display a chart showing per-month sales; I want to display the volume as one column and the sales as a different column (both in each month). The problem, however, is that I have multiple sales values for each month, one per currency. I wanted this to be a stacked column, showing the different values one on top of the other.

My problem is that when I make the second series stacked column, it stacks it on top of the first value. I don't want that. Can someone explain how to configure this correctly?

Example data:

- Jan 2011: qty 30, sales: 10 USD, 15 GBP, 0 EUR
- Feb 2011: qty 40, sales: 20 USD, 5 GBP, 5 EUR
- Mar 2011: qty 80, sales: 30 USD, 10 GBP, 10 EUR

I am using the default chart control in Visual Studio 2010. This is a WinForms application, not web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [StackedGroupName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456744.aspx) custom property.

> To place multiple series in the same stacked group, assign the same
>   name to them.
>
> To show multiple stacks, assign different names to multiple series.

From the samples project:

```
// Set the first two series to be grouped into Group1
chart1.Series["LightBlue"]["StackedGroupName"] = "Group1";
chart1.Series["Gold"]["StackedGroupName"] = "Group1";

// Set the last two series to be grouped into Group2
chart1.Series["Red"]["StackedGroupName"] = "Group2";
chart1.Series["DarkBlue"]["StackedGroupName"] = "Group2";
```

Comment: Great! I'm glad I decided to post an answer even though the question was 10 months old. :)